# How the wave vector $k$ change slowly and travel a loop in Brillouin zone when we calculate the Berry phase?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topology, electronic-band-theory, berry-pancharatnam-phase

According to the definition of the Berry phase, there must have a slowly changing parameter that travel a loop. when we discuss topology in energy band, the slowly changing parameter seems the $k$. my question is how the particle's momentum could slowly changing and travel a loop in Brillouin zone.

Comment: In a "slowly changing" i.e. adiabatic loop, it is the Hamiltonian that is changing. We are not following a particle around, we are keeping track of an energy eigenstate while the Hamiltonian is changing.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i'm still a little confused. so does it mean a parameter of Hamiltonian must changing and back to its initial values? when we discuss the topological energy band, it seems all the parameter of Hamiltonian are conservation.